# Fragment objects after the fragment is destroyed; when GC collects them?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, garbage-collection

I have a fragment, and inside that fragment i start a worker thread, which does something that can take a few seconds. After the worker thread is finished, i have to insert something to a sqlite database by calling mDatabaseHandler.insertSomething(something) (mDatabaseHandler is a private instance inside the fragment).

Inside the worker thread I don't access any views created by the UI thread, but I access the objects that was created in that fragment. What happens if I remove that fragment or destroy it? I've read that when fragment is removed onDestroyView is called. But I'm not sure what happens to other objects. I tried to do some operations in the onDestroy method of the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Client client = mDatabaseHandler.getTheLastClient();
    Log.e(TAG, "Client full name: " + client.getFullName());
}
```

Everything worked fine. So my final question is: when will the GC collect the objects that were created in the fragment after the fragment is destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are keeping a reference to an object in fragment. Fragment will not be garbage collected until thread is finished or it releases the reference to the object in fragment. If an object has a **strong reference**, gc will not collect it. In your case, you are keeping a reference to object in fragment, hence an implicit reference to fragment object and leaking memory (now garbage collector will not be able to reclaim memory occupied by fragment)

You should keep a `weak reference` to that object and while using that object, check if it is still available or not (either weak reference returns object or null).

You can read more about weak reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).